# What does “tm” mean?

Tags: slang, internet-slang

I think it is an Internet slang, but found a few times on the web.

Example:

> 自大，在超市贵的东西都是写着纯国产 以前在语言学校的时候写作文 主题都是你认为日本哪里好 为什么喜欢日本 我**tm**是被逼来的 硬是编出来说日本人很有礼貌 日本的公共设施做得好 日本老师看着还一本满足 那副嘴脸真的很恶心。

What does “tm” mean? I searched on the web and found it means 他妈妈, but then it means 我他妈妈是 and does not make sense...

Comment: TM = 他媽, short for the vulgar 他媽的 = motherf*****g.

Comment: @droooze Ah, just got to know 他妈 is a slang, not the literal “his mother”! Thanks

Comment: It's (obviously) also written TMD. Anyway there's a whole bunch of acronyms and funny abbreviations people use that get updated quite often, mostly to escape censorship, and you might find some of these in [another question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/other-than-chinasmack-do-any-other-glossaries-of-acronyms-used-in-chinese-like).

Comment: @droooze Thanks and do you mind writing it up in an answer?

Comment: high scores seem puzzling,since TM occurs all the time on web， as 他妈（的）it has been the topic of previous Q (search this site with 他妈)

Comment: @user6065 how can someone to know to search 他媽 if they didn't know what TM means? I actually tried the same search myself, before this question/answer nothing actually turned up. That's why I agreed to write an answer for it.

Comment: As that many dirty words are banned in most websites in China, so people may choose variant versions like initialism from **pinyin** like **TM** / **TMD** from **ta ma** / **ta ma de**,  or some other homophones, like 踏马, etc.

Comment: for example: 这天气真TM好！ or 这天气真踏马好！ equals to 这天气真他妈好！

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TM** (also written **TMD**) is short for **他/她媽的**, literally ('his/her mother's'), equivalent to English **motherf*****g**.

See [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%96%E5%AA%BD%E7%9A%84) for more details.

Comment: The implicit noun after 他妈的 is B ([q.v.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B1%84)).

Answer (score 4):

TM, TMD: 他妈，他妈的/地.

Depending on contexts, it could be interpreted differently:

1. Damn it! // (她)妈的
2. What the f**k are you doing? // 你TM在干嘛？
3. Damn hot! // 真TMD热！
4. What the f**king door is this? // 这是TM什么(破)门？
   ... ...